# How to install ruby-dbi on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

I tried to install ruby-dbi on Ubuntu 20.04 however it failed with the following

```
osboxes@osboxes:/tmp$ sudo apt install ruby-dbi
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ruby-dbi
```

I found some articles for ruby-dbi on Ubuntu 18.04.  However, I could not find any article for Ubuntu 20.04

Kindly let me know installation process for ruby-dbi on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: i am using ubuntu 18.04 and i get the same error, looks like the error is not because of ubuntu version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ruby-dbi` package is not included in any supported version of Ubuntu. However, from the name of the package, it might be that this used to package the [dbi](https://rubygems.org/gems/dbi) gem. This gem is now unmaintained for 10 years and will certainly not work on any supported version of Ruby.

To use a database-independent wrapper, you might want to use a maintained gem instead. Common choices are either to use [Sequel](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel) or [ActiveRecord](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activerecord).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I'll try Sequel or ActiveRecord as suggested